# Automorphisms of simple tree with coloring set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, coloring

Find a number of different coloring of set

$$ V = \left\{1, ..., 6 \right\} $$ in use of $2$ colors. We treat two coloring like the same if they belong to the same orbit of the group tree automorphisms with the set of vertices V and the set of edges
$$ \left\{  \left\{1,3 \right\},  \left\{2,3 \right\} , \left\{3,4 \right\}, \left\{ 4,5 \right\},  \left\{4,6 \right\}     \right\}  $$

### Solution

Permutation $f$ is automorphism of $G$ if and only if
$$  \left\{u,v \right\} \in E \text{ if and only if }  \left\{f(v), f(w) \right\}  \in E  $$
We should find chromatic polynomial:
$$W(x) = x^6 $$

so $W(2) = 64 $
Now, lets find number of automorphism (I have no experience with that before this task)
$$ 1 \rightarrow 5/6 \\
2 \rightarrow 6/5 \\
3 \rightarrow 4/4 \\
4 \rightarrow 3/3 \\
5 \rightarrow 1/2 \\
6 \rightarrow 2/1$$
so we have $2$ permutations so our answer is
$$ \frac{64}{2} = 32$$
Can somebody check this solution?

Comment: It seems to me that the tree has $8$ automorphisms: $4$ that leave vertices $3$ and $4$ fixed, and $4$ that interchange them.